# Facebook returning querystring body instead of json

Tags: json, facebook

I have a problem reading the response from facebook when authenticating on the url with [curl](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=yyy&client_secret=XXXX&code=YYY&redirect_uri=ZZZ)

The response that comes back in the body is:
access_token=XXX&expires=5435

My question is: `How do I make Facebook reply with Json data?`

I have tried adding `Content-Type:json` to the request headers but it does not help.

Thanks for any help!

Br

Niclas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an exception on the Graph API. /oauth/access_token is the only point that doesn't return JSON, as far as I know.

Comment: This has been fixed since Graph API v2.3 released in 2015, cf. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/archive "[Oauth Access Token] Format ... We made this update to be compliant with section 5.1 of RFC 6749."

Answer (score 1):

It's a **bug**: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325262010847554?browse=search_4f99eacc521fc2634034618

It violates the OAuth 2.0 spec (which FB is co-authoring!): https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25#section-5.1

I agree - they should at least honor the `Accept: application/json` header!

See also a similar question, here: [Facebook oauth/access_token missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862108/facebook-oauth-access-token-missing/3865112#3865112)